# Cordova, iOS dark keyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, keyboard

I have already read the previous posts on the subject matter dating back in 2013 but it seems that things have changed not can seem to find any Cordova plugins to allow for such feature.

Therefore is there a way for me to modify my xCode project for every keyboard to be black themed and ideally with some transparency?

Comment: Anyone? Thank you for reading this!

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I found this updated post on a possible solution -- perhaps this will help?
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/keyboard-plugin-question/27597/7

It should definitely be possible. It is very aggravating that no one added a dark keyboard to cordova.

Should raise a ticket with this GitHub of ionic-plugin-keyboard -- it seems they have code there for this but it's commented out. Perhaps need a squeaky wheel there to get this going: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard/blob/master/src/ios/IonicKeyboard.m#L84

Comment: Thank you Mark. So close! Just need the iOS 9 now. Let me know if you get any luck with your ticket on the ionic-plugin-keyboard git repo.